# Custom Tag Content Not Showing In Preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I'm using the following custom tag in my template:

```
<div style="font-size:14px;color:#000000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;margin-    bottom:10px;line-height:130%;">
<custom type="content" name="bodyCopy"></custom>
</div>
```

When I insert HTML Only content in it, it works fine and shows up in the  HTML tab, but when I switch to the PREVIEW tab, there's nothing there at all. The only other tags I have is one for a hero image and the tracking tag.

```
<custom type="content" name="Hero Image">
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have experienced with the template engine. If you look near the top of your template at the META tags you most likely haven't closed the tags; even though its not strictly required to close your meta tags the template preview has an issue when rendering your email if it finds a meta tag thats not properly closed.

For example you may currently have a tag in the template that looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Close your meta tag so your code looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This resolved my issues, hopefully it fixes your problem too.